# Making filters with GET parameters

Tags: forms

By web standards it is good practice when we have filter forms to be with GET method.

For example if we can have form with one input for searching videos. 
Submitting the form will lead to

www.site.com/?query=metallica

In many businesses there are cases when the thing people search should be private or people doesn't want for the query to stay in browser history.

For example if you have field to search your credit cards by number it will save in browser history as get parameter which is bad. This is just an example.

Or if I search contact by phone number -> www.site.com/search/?phone=123456 this way every human that uses the same computer will have the numbers from previous. (supposing the form is public)

So is there any exception and one correct way to handle this.

Making the form with POST method or similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can always get the form input data using javascript and then perform a GET or POST request on an RESTful API endpoint on your server, and render the result on the page. Using JavaScript only. Browser are implementing POST request for this reason, user privacy and hide request body from the url. Also for privacy reasons, you should use HTTPS.

Comment: This will not work if the browser doesnt have javascript or is disabled or something crashes - in that case the form will be submitted normal and even in https the get parameters stay in the history. If POST method is used this violates the standards which say POST method will modify something on the server. So in both cases something is bad.

Comment: browsers only implement GET and POST requests only. Can I ask you about what standard are you talking about?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods 
POST
    The POST method is used to submit an entity to the specified resource, often causing a change in state or side effects on the server.

Comment: Those are the protocol method documentation, not a standard, like an ISO. Anyway, browser forms support only GET and POST request. Since GET requests have no body, you must either place the query in the URL or make a POST request, witch on the mozzila link you provided says that it **OFTEN** causes a change on the server (it does not says always)